# How could i make the NestedList Toolbar invisible

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How could i make the NestedList Toolbar invisible and the config => `useToolbar: true`.
[image]

Comment: With a good old CSS display:none on the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not tested but try this.

```
nesteslist.getDockedItems()[0].setHidden(true);
```